# How to use glide in asynctask in android

Tags: android

I am using asynctask in my activity to fetch data from server.The data which is returned from server is in JSON format.The json data also contains an image url value in it and the image is stored on server.Now after fetching data in doInBackground() method i store a json object and send to onPostExecute() method.In onPostExecute method by using glide i fetch image from server like this.

```
var jsonobj: JSONObject = link_array.getJSONObject(i)
                val sb = StringBuilder()
                val link = Globals.link
                sb.append(link + "/").append(jsonobj.getString("url"))
                var c = sb.toString()
                var bitmap: Bitmap = Glide.with(activity!!).asBitmap().load(c).submit().get()
                var image = bitmap
```

I am fetching image and then i stored in Bitmap variable type.But it gives me an error that i should use glide on backgroud thread.Glide is used for image fetching purpose and it runs in background but here why it gives me an error.
The glide version which i am using is

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

So my question is how can i fetch an image using Glide in onPostExecute method and store it in a Bitmap variable type.The code works fine when i uses it in doInBackground() method,but i don't want that because it make loading data slow.

Comment: Why you are trying to get the image into a Bitmap? Is there any special purpose?

Answer (score 3):

`onPostExecute` runs on main thread, so you’d have to fetch the bitmap on the background.

You can pass url into Glide though, it’ll handle it:

```
Glide.with(context).load(„your_url_here”).into(your_imageview)
```

Comment: can i store that image in bitmap .If yes? then how?

Comment: Your bitmap fetching task must run on background, so you need to implement it in some way. ASyncTasks are not that great, I’d recommend to get familiar with [Kotlin coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) and use them instead

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to have the `AsyncTask` for the `Glide` to perform your operations in the background. `Glide` itself will take care of it and will not interfere with your main thread.

Comment: suppose you have json object and that json object contains a link to image and u returned it from doInBackground() method to onPostexecute().Now when u call glide in this method then it gives error.why?

Comment: Maybe you are not able to reference the image properly?